# Why is my python code to solve a quadratic formula doing this?

Tags: python, math

So I am quite a novice at coding python, so I decided to try my hand at making a quadratic equation solver. After entering all my user inputted variables i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/insertnamehere/Desktop/quadratic formula solver.py", line 6, in <module>
    root=math.sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c)
ValueError: math domain error
```

My code is:

```
import math

a=float(input("A?: "))
b=float(input("B?: "))
c=float(input("C?: "))
root=math.sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c)
x=(-b+root)/2*a
x2=(-b-root)/2*a
print(x)
print(x2)
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Edit:
Forgot to add the actual values i entered.

```
A?: 6
B?: 1
C?: 2
```

Comment: your code is wrongly indented. please correct.

Comment: why do you `import random`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was planning on adding a randomly generated quadratic and showing the steps needed to solve it as another feature. As for the indentation, that was simply an error in putting the code onto this post.

Comment: Debus: don't worry. Do you understand the solutions proposed?

Comment: Yes, I now realize that the inputted data was what was causing the problem, I should of thought of one myself instead of googling for a sample quadratic.

Comment: um, what is "a sample quadratic"?

Comment: By that i mean a random quadratic that I found on Google.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you used google to chose three random coefficents?

Comment: Yes, i wanted one with the solutions, to make sure the program worked as it should. what I'm saying is that i should of thought of them myself and calculated the answer, instead of being lazy.

Comment: ... really, you need help guessing three arbitrary real numbers, and calculating the solution of the generated quadratic homegenous equation? Really, really make sure you understand the math behind why `sqrt` isn't working here.

Comment: Not that I needed help, more that I could not be bothered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python can handle complex numbers, but the `math` module won't do square roots of negative numbers, for that you need to use [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.sqrt).

Demo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cmath

a = 1.0
b = 1.0
c = 1.0

root = cmath.sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c)
x1 = (-b + root) / (2.0 * a)
x2 = (-b - root) / (2.0 * a)
print x1
print x2
```

**output**

```
(-0.5+0.866025403784j)
(-0.5-0.866025403784j)
```

Although `i` is commonly used by mathematicians as the symbol for the square root of negative one, Python uses `j`; that convention is common among electronics engineers, since they use `i` to represent current.

So the above output is equal to (-1 ± sqrt(-3))/2

Comment: I see, Thank you for the help. I will rewrite this using the cmath module instead.

Comment: Oh,@Debus: sorry that I've misjudged you. I was assuming you weren't aware of complex numbers.

Comment: I was not aware python had a cmath module as well as a math module, reading the documentation for cmath now.

Comment: @Debus: If you like my answer you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. That way, people will know that your question has been answered satisfactorily. And we'll both get some points. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a basic 9th grad math question:

Quadratic equations don't always have real-valued solutions, because you can't take the square root of a negative number. You've entered values for a quadratic equation that simply can't be solved within the real numbers.

EDIT: you posted your values:

so, what **is** the square root of (1² - 2*6*2) ? You cannot find a solution in the real numbers to that question, and neither can python, that's why it's giving you a math domain error.

Look at it this way: 6x² + x + 2 = 0 really has no real solution. Hint: Look at the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ef5dqt5nd05&mail=1)